# img elements not taking dimensions as in other browsers

Tags: html, css, reactjs, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

In react, I have an img tag :

```
<img className="invert-image" src= {commitFilled} alt=""/>

.invert-image{
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
}
```

It is rendering perfectly fine in all browsers, except in IE 11. In IE 11, it renders with a small size. I even tried with px but no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `className`?

Comment: @TanDuong it is in react

Comment: can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? I put your code in [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/n6wysgde/3/) (using actual HTML though) and it behaves as expected in IE.